# Plotting png plot from matplotlib in flask displays raw data

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

The following snippet of code generates a matplotlib plot and returns a png:

```
@app.route('/plot/')    
def test_image():
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
        plt.plot(np.arange(100), np.random.normal(0, 1, 100))
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        img = BytesIO()
        fig.savefig(img)
        img.seek(0)
        return send_file(img, mimetype='image/png')
```

Embedding this in html:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('test_image') }}" alt="Image Placeholder" height="300">
```

works as expected.
However, when trying to update the image using jquery:

```
$.get('/plot', function(image){
          $("#weapImage").html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+image+'" />')
      })
```

displays the image as raw data
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that base64 encoding was necessary:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    plt.plot(np.arange(100), np.random.normal(0, 1, 100))
    img = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(img)
    img.seek(0)
    resp = Response(response=base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()),
                    status=200, mimetype="image/png")
    return resp
```